# Merge same variables into one and add append it its attributes in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can I convert the following list (scaled example) in pandas by taking all of the same variables making them into one and then adding their attributes? The first column is variable and the second is its value:

```
A  1.1
A  1.4
A  1.2
B  2.1
B  2.4
V  3.1
V  3.2
```

To something more usable like:

```
 A    B    V
1.1  2.1  3.1
1.4  2.4  3.2
1.2
```

Comment: if you downvote please let me know why so that I can avoid it next time..!

Comment: I dont see a downvote

Comment: I have looked for two weeks now and can not find a solution even though this might seem like an easy task for a more experienced developer, if someone has posted an answer already I would appreciate it if you could point me to it

Comment: I made the comment for the downvoat before I saw yours..! it was for everyone

Comment: I found the answer from the duplicates mentioned above, do I delete this or leave it as is..?

Comment: its ohk to leave it. Sometimes dupes lead to the main answer.